# Examples of 3D Javascript of CSS3 animations in-browser on iOS?

Tags: ios, graphics, mobile-safari, javascript, animation

Are there any examples of **3D** animations rendering in mobile Safari? To date, nearly all of the 3D animations I've seen working on a PC don't seem to render correctly on iOS. (Why is that?)

I was under the impression that because of full hardware acceleration, 3D animation would be no problem in mobile Safari, especially since mobile Safari is pretty standards compliant and supports both Javascript, HTML 5 and CSS3 quite well.

If there are no examples, why not? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 1):

3D CSS works well on mobile safari.

- http://www.clicktorelease.com/code/css3dclouds/
- https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/vr.php
- http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/3dcss/demo